# Overlay subtitles over Web videos

Tags: linux, video, web-browser, closed-captions

I’m looking for a way to overlay subtitles when watching a video on the Web.

Features:

- It should work for every kind of video, no matter which player is used (Flash, HTML5 `video`, …).
- It should also work in full screen mode.
- I’m adding the subtitles, so the tool does not have to search for them.
- The tool does not have to synchronize the subtitles with the video, as long as I can manually pause/fast-forward and rewind the subtitles.

Formal requirements:

- It can be a stand-alone tool or a browser add-on.
- It must run natively on GNU/Linux.
- FLOSS is preferred but not required.

I found [JustSubsPlayer](http://justsubsplayer.codeplex.com/) (beta from 2010), but it’s for Windows. I did not test it, but according to its description it is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **VLC** as follows:

- in case of YouTube videos just open the URL in VLC. It will get the video and you can add subtitles to it.
- for other sites you can use [tubeoffline.com](http://www.tubeoffline.com/) to get the direct URL which you can play in VLC. Go to Tubeoffline, select the site you found the video on and put the link there. Let it load and start playing it in their flash based player, then click `Generate`. When the download button appears, right-click on it and choose `Copy link address`. Well that address you can sure play in VLC.

After that go to `Subtitles` Menu and choose `Add subtitles`.

Advantages:

- works with all the sites supported by Tubeoffline
- fullscreen mode, aspect ratio tweak etc.
- manually add any subtitles VLC can handle
- play, pause video
- sync subtitles
- FLOSS running on Linux

Disadvantages:

- too many steps required to get an URL
- there are some unsupported sites

Look in this screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Video shown here is from [Tubeoffline](http://www.tubeoffline.com/download-VK-videos.php)'s link example.

Comment: Very nice solution. This is even preferable to overlaying subtitles. (-- However, I’m still looking for an overlaying solution, e.g., for those streams not supported by *tubeoffline.com*.)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as all of you do. I have developed **Penguin Subtitle Player**, an open-source, cross-platform standalone subtitle player which fulfils your requirements perfectly. It can handle different encodings so subtitles in Chinese and any other languages can be displayed properly.

- Github repo: https://github.com/carsonip/Penguin-Subtitle-Player
- Download: https://sourceforge.net/projects/penguinsubtitleplayer/

And of course, you are welcome to contribute or leave comments.

Comment: Could you please comple it [with Windows XP support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx)?

Comment: It'd be great if it had hotkeys to go 5 seconds forward or backwards

Comment: @Shayan it would be hard to intercept key events for a non-foreground process, especially when it is cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I wanted to use greenfish under wine but it didn't support Chinese. I developed this a few days ago. It's not as good as greenfish but it works. It will play most unicode srt files. You can replace the font file if you need a different font. I hope it helps.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplesubsplayer