# Adding closed captions to online videos

Tags: video, speech-recognition, closed-captions

I am looking for a program/browser extension that can generate [closed captions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_captioning) on any video I watch online.

I like to watch a lot of YouTube tutorials, breaking news, and general information videos online but I can't always have the volume turned on because I'm at work. It would be nice to have closed captions be generated for those videos so I can know what they're saying.

It would be great if the closed captions were only a second or so behind what the person is saying (like on TV), but if there needs to be more of a delay for processing, that's fine too.

Comment: And do you want that program/extension to automatically generate closed captions? Or do you have a subtitle file?

Comment: @Cornelius I would want them to be generated on the fly (Question Updated)

Comment: YouTube already has an experimental function that can do that.

Comment: @Cornelius I'll have to check out that YouTube feature. Many major news sites don't have that feature though.

Comment: For cases where you have a subtitle file, see the question: [Overlay subtitles over Web videos](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3608/60)