# Software to create automatic subtitles (OS X)

Tags: osx, video, speech-recognition, closed-captions

You know how Youtube creates "automatic" subtitles based on the sound on a video? (sound-to-text)

I have an MP4 file on my computer. How do I create "automatic" subtitles based on the video's sound, for free? (sound-to-text) I don't want to type up the subtitles by hand, I want sound-to-text to create them automatically.

I don't see how [this page](http://www.instructionblog.com/index/2011/08/how-to-create-srt-subtitles-in-mac-os-x/) is helpful for automatic subtitles.

As a final note, I use a Mac, version 10.9.

Comment: For Web videos, see the question: [Adding closed captions to online videos](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3987/60)

Comment: wow, just that i had on my mind. +200

Comment: No guarantees, but try this: download the video, split it up into one-hour segments, upload unlisted or private, create closed captions (automatic), enjoy the correct parts and laugh at the mistakes.

Answer (score 9):

This is one of the dreams of many many people and **currently a perfect solution is *not* publicly available**. However it can still be done with a bit of messy work. One method which will work if a) the video is okay to be public for a few minutes and b) Youtube's auto-captioning will work is to upload to [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com), get Youtube to auto-caption and then use [KeepSubs](http://keepsubs.com/) web-app to download the subtitles, then delete video.

Then it is a simple matter of finding the subtitle editor with the features you need/want. [AegisSub](http://www.aegisub.org/) is a high-quality subtitle editor/applier which should work for what you need.

Comment: This is a good hijacking trick. However, YouTube does not create automatic subtitles to all videos.

Comment: :( --  KeepSubs seems to be gone at this point.  There may be others.  I'll edit if I find one.

Answer (score 3):

This Python 2 script use Google Web Speech API and FFmpeg to generate subtitles: https://github.com/agermanidis/autosub

Comment: That sounds amazing!

Answer (score 2):

There is also another option but it is *even* more work for you.

That is using speech->text engine and a double-male 3.5mm audio cable to route your speaker output to your mic input. The quality will be based on the quality of the text-speech engine. The best engine I know that will work on Macs is [Dragon Dictate](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-mac/dragon-dictate/index.htm) (I have used the windows version - Dragon Naturally Speaking - rather than the Mac version).

Then it is a simple matter of finding the subtitle editor with the features you need/want. [AegisSub](http://www.aegisub.org/) is a high-quality subtitle editor/applier which should work for what you need.

Then more works comes again; you have to set the timing up (through the subtitle editor) and check for errors ofc.

In summary it's a nasty amount of work and not very automated but slightly better than hand entering usually - if it has poor audio quality you may be able to take less time just manually doing it all rather than editing horribly inaccurate speech->text engine results.

Answer (score 0):

Gaupol 0.19.2 (Python) use GStreamer 0.10 (with plugin PocketSphinx 0.7) to recognize speech and create automatic timings. I have not tested newer versions.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gaupol/SpeechRecognition

I am using Linux, but maybe it's possible to run them on OS X too.

Comment: Support can be added in new version too: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=757743