# Automatic subtitle synchronization

Tags: video, speech-recognition, accessibility, closed-captions

I have subtitles without timing and I need to automatically sync them to a video.

After some searching, I found

- http://www.jaivox.com/wordalign.html
- http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2014/07/long-audio-aligner-landed-in-trunk/
- https://bitbucket.org/natsuhh/prosub/

I would like a recommendation for a software that can sync my subtitles. Preferably based on personal experience.

I have access to Linux and Windows. I prefer offline tool although online is fine too. Video and subtitle formats have no impact: I can convert the video and subtitles into something the aligning tool can work with.

Comment: related  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4319/how-to-create-automatic-subtitles

Comment: YouTube has an "Automatic timing" feature for transcripts in English
Dutch
French
German
Italian
Japanese
Korean
Portuguese
Russian
Spanish https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734799?hl=en

Comment: That looks like an answer. Would you post it as such? Keep in mind that here on SR.SE comments are "second class citizens" and can be gone any day. Please also explain how it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube has an "Automatic timing" feature for transcripts in English, Dutch, French German, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Portuguese, Russian, and Spanish.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734799?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Here is anothe way:

1. Load the original videos in the foreign language to [Whisper API](https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions), or install [Whisper LLM locally](https://github.com/openai/whisper)
2. Let Whisper transcribe the  video , return as .srt file. This will contain very precise marks.
3. Paste .srt files into Google Translate or some other translation service
4. Compare the machine-translations with your preexisting translations manually, replace machine translated stuff with manually crafted translations

> Update 2024: Google now enforces a 5000 character limit in their translate.google.com web GUI. Stitching together many 5000-character chunks of translated text is possible via the web interface but it is tedious and the results and the "joints" are so-so.