# Software that gives closed captioning to YouTube Videos

Tags: closed-captions, transcription

I make YouTube videos and I want to add closed captioning to my videos. But I'm not a transcriber and I can't afford to hire one. The options for such software overwhelms me. I need software that works on a MacBook Air, is preferably free, and can make closed captions for .mov files. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/adding-closed-captions-to-online-videos - although that has no answer.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube creates closed captions automatically using their speech-to-text software. Here’s how:

1. Login to your YouTube channel, go to the Video Manager and select the video you want to caption.
2. Above the video you will see a range of options, including “Subtitles and CC”. Click this.
3. You will be asked to specify what language is used throughout the majority of your video.
4. Once you have specified a language, you should see the automatic captions appear as caption tack in the list to the right of your video. Select this, then choose “Edit” from the options.
5. You can now edit a copy of the automatic caption track that YouTube’s speech-to-text facility has produced.

Hope it will help...